# Changing the heading of a Windows Form Aplication

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to make a Windows Form Application using C#, Most programs have a heading like if you load a MS Word Document it says Document1 and after you save it the name changes to the name of the new saved document. I want my program to change the heading every time I open a clients name.  I wrote a quick note pad application as to where it could be shown best what I want.
The name changes from "New text File" to "Test 1"
I want to know if there is a code one can use to change it accordingly.

Comment: `The name changes from "New text File" to "Test 1"` so it's working? What's the problem?

Comment: @eddie_cat I *think* he's saying it works that way in Notepad, and he wants it in his application.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET saying "I wrote a quick note pad application" makes it seem like he wrote a text editor. But you are probably right.

Comment: @eddie_cat Thats how I read it at first to, then realized that it was unlikely he wrote a text editor :)

Comment: Could you provide us with what you have so far so we can help you better?

Answer (score 2):

You do this by simply setting the `Text` property of the `Form` object ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form(v=vs.110).aspx)).

For example:

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    private void SomeMethd()
    {
       Text = "MyTitle";
       //Or explicitly, this.Text = "MyTitle";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the text on the title bar of your application, you use the `Text` property:

```
Text = "Untitled.txt - My Application";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Text` property of the form:

```
this.Text = "client name";
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a property of you form
frmName.Text = "newFormNamehere";

Comment: Actually it definitely is :)

Comment: It's been a while since I last used c# :D

Comment: It has nothing to do with C# though. It's the same as Web Page `title` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Header with the Text Attribute.

```
Form1.Text = "NewText"
```